# Intellij IDEA: fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I was working with my project with `git` within `Intellij IDEA` and everything was fine. Then I created a new repository which included the current one. I have updated `Version Control` section in `Preferences` to point to a new root folder, where IDE shown me two 'Git roots'. I included both.

Result: IDEA does not track any changes in files and pop ups the error: `fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'`. Also IDE states all my files are not versioned. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Could you rephrase this and explain what you have done more carefully, with illlustrations if necessary? It's difficult to tell from the description.

Comment: Sorry, I rephrased the explanation a little bit.

Comment: From a previous question, I think a file could not be in two Git repo, so nested repo will not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just create a git directory on a parent directory of a repository, and expect things to work. It would help to know what you are actually trying to **achieve**, but a wild guess is that you probably want to have a look at [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Answer (score 0):

this is generally caused by `.git` directory being nested in the actual workspace , so you will have to remove the nested  `.git` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Ok It's a while since this was opened but this is not true, you can have a nested git structure on some repo's I've worked on the project has a git folder as does each plugin folder. The nested folders are however ignored with a gitignore file. This is a different issue. My solution was to delete the .git folder and start again as this was a new project, in my case i renamed the directory and project as i had had a typo in the name.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue in my case:

1. Unregister problematic *version control root* from IDE settings and click OK:

   [image]
2. Reopen and add (register) it again:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

My program crashed during a git push. Similar error. I restored the previous version of the folder .git

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).